# Is it a good practice to use Gmail, Yahoo Mail & Hotmail addresses for registration?

Tags: email, registration

I am designing a website in which clients should register to use some specific services, and I am trying to prevent temp mails, or mails from personal domain.

The question is that is this a good practice to use Gmail, Yahoo mail, Hotmail and some other well-known mail services?

Do you have a domain in which you implemented registration system? If the answer is positive, do we have people from other mail services? (how many?)

Comment: This question can't be answered without knowing what the purpose of your website is, and which email domains you do consider acceptable. For reference, I've been using Gmail since 2005/2006 and I wouldn't use a tool that didn't let me register with that email address.

Comment: Is this question about social sign-in or about using free email addresses to register? Because the chosen answer is about social sign-in, but your question is phrased like it's about dealing with temporary email addresses.

Comment: well I actually meant prevent spam registration, I mean users have to use well-known email addresses for signing-up, but I liked the way webmasters answered my question ;) if you have any answer for my question I welcome it with open arms.

Comment: @web designer: I think the 2 existing answers cover both pretty well. I was just wondering if the question needed to be rephrased. But it's probably fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Gmail, Yahoo Mail, Hotmail or other login api's. This is good practice because the user doesn't want to register on many sites and remember the login details. It irritates the user. They prefer to use these service to login each time.

This increases the programmers effort in retrieving and handling the data, but from the users point of view this is better.

You can use [openId services](http://openid.net/developers/) to accomplish it.

Answer (score 3):

It's not if you decide to limit your users' login options to those domains.

Many people will use services like yahoo.ca or yahoo.cn or AOL or their ISP or company domain as a primary mail service. You are disabling all of them from your website.

*Note that users who use their company or personal websites as primary emails are usually advanced users who will likely be more valuable than others.*

Even those who have emails in one of the services you offer with the domains you support (because most of these services have internationalization domains), they will be offended by seeing this, and will likely be a minus point for your site.

Alternatively, offer those as OpenID services, optionally. This will encourage any of the users of those services to use them to login, so, most of your users will come from those services, which is good enough.